# Observe WCF service call with RX

Tags: c#, wcf, system.reactive

I have a WCF heartbeat service accepting keep alives from clients. If keep alive does not arrive within specified time a timeout is raised and some action taken. Now, I'm trying to simplify existing code that uses System.Threading.Timer and replace it with a solution based on RX. What I'm missing is how to convert WCF service method class to observable. What I've considered are the following:

- Implementing IObservable in WCF service and cache observers passed as Subscribe parameters, probably not a good idea and ugly code
- Use Subject like this:

  ```
   Subject s1 = new Subject();
   s1.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
     .Subscribe(_ => { }, ex => Console.WriteLine("Timeout at " + DateTime.Now));
  ```

  Console.WriteLine("Hertbeat at: " + DateTime.Now);
   s1.OnNext(Unit.Default);
   Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
   Console.WriteLine("Hertbeat at: " + DateTime.Now);
   s1.OnNext(Unit.Default);

  this works, but probably using subjects in production code is not a good idea.

  - Use events in service's implementation:

  ```
  class HeartbeatService
  {
    public void Heartbeat()
    {
      OnHeartbeatArrived();
    }
  ```

  public event Action HeartbeatArrived;

  protected virtual void OnHeartbeatArrived()
    {
  Action handler = HeartbeatArrived;
  if (handler != null) handler(Unit.Default);
    }
  }

and then use RX

```
HeartbeatService heartbeatService = new HeartbeatService();
Observable.FromEvent<Unit>(action => heartbeatService.HeartbeatArrived += action,
                           action => heartbeatService.HeartbeatArrived -= action)
  .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
  .Subscribe(_ => { },
             ex => Console.WriteLine("Timeout " + ex + ", at " + DateTime.Now));

Console.WriteLine("Heartbeat at: " + DateTime.Now);
heartbeatService.Heartbeat();
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
Console.WriteLine("Heartbeat at: " + DateTime.Now);
heartbeatService.Heartbeat();
Console.WriteLine("Should timeout now");
```

I don't like this solution either, event in WCF service seems superfluous.
Is there a good way of doing that in RX or maybe I'm trying to misuse RX here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Throttle` operator is the crucial piece to heartbeat algos in Rx. The basic idea is to set up a stream containing an alert that is suppressed as long as heartbeats arrive. See my blog post here for more detail: http://www.zerobugbuild.com/?p=230

Comment: Thanks James. I used Timeout instead of Throttle because it terminates the sequence: http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/13_TimeShiftedSequences.html#Timeout. In your blog post you are suggesting usage of Subjects while my question was how to eliminate the need of Subjects. But maybe Subjects are the way to go and there is no cleaner and better solution for that.

Comment: You have to enter the monad somehow... Subjects, FromEventXXX... Whatever. All the same thing in the end. The bad thing is to needlessly jump in and out of the monad - that the usual form of Subject abuse. You can use Throttle + Take(1) to get termination btw.